# Using ASP.NET dynamic data web app. along side ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm working on a project and building a website.
For user's i create a asp.net mvc project and my admin panel should work with ASP.NET dynamic data for inserting and deleting and updating site's data.
So i have some challenges for creating this project.
How i can create authentication with session in my Dynamic data Site?
And how i can redirect between these two projects?

Comment: Store session state in db would probably be best bet.

Answer (score 0):

> How i can create authentication with session in my Dynamic data Site?

I would use [ASP.NET membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx).

> And how i can redirect between these two projects?

I would use Response.Redirect